# A children's plaything

Tags: riddle

A quick little riddle about a peculiar object. See how quickly you can figure it out based on the mysterious clues below. The correct answer will be awarded to the first person to identify the object and explain how each line fits

> You can find me underwater, but I won't be wet.
>   You can find me in the air too, but I can't cross in between.
>   In either case, I charge to my death, spilling my guts.
>   If you touch me, I will die but if you carry me, you will die.
>   If you guess the wrong thing, the OP will have to kill me.

Comment: Who is the OP??

Comment: Original Poster, aka: me

Comment: Oh, understood...

Comment: @MarcosSartorato I also sometimes have problems understanding such shortcuts. I always use [this site](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_von_Abk%C3%BCrzungen_%28Netzjargon%29) for finding out what it means. Even though it is german you will also find the english meaning of the shortcut. (I haven't found an english site that features this list yet)

Comment: @MarcosSartorato Actually I found some english ones now, see [this](http://www.acronymfinder.com/) and [this](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/) site

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The object described is:

> A bubble

You can find me underwater, but I won't be wet.

> A bubble underwater will be dry inside.

You can find me in the air too, but I can't cross in between.

> Bubbles can also float in the air, but they cannot burst through the surface of the water

In either case, I charge to my death, spilling my guts

> Eventually bubbles of any sort will burst, releasing the gas inside them.

If you touch me, I will die but if you carry me, you will die.

> If you try to touch a bubble it will usually burst, but if you have a bubble in your blood it will kill you

If you guess the wrong thing, the OP will have to kill me.

> If This guess is wrong, then @NeedAName will have to burst my bubble

And

> Children like to play with bubbles.

Comment: Well done Mr. K! First one to get the correct object and explain each line of the riddle. You are quite the riddle slayer

Comment: @NeedAName Only occasionally when it jumps out at me!

Answer (score 5):

Could you be a...

> bubble?

You can find me underwater, but I won't be wet.

> bubbles are not wet

You can find me in the air too, but I can't cross in between.

> soapbubbles can exist in air, but an underwater bubble will cease to exist when not surrounded by water

In either case, I charge to my death, spilling my guts.

> bubbles charges to the surface and pop

If you touch me, I will die but if you carry me, you will die.

> if you touch a bubble it will die. air bubbles carried in your blood flow can be very hazardous.

If you guess the wrong thing, the OP will have to kill me.

> i don't know about this one.

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> a bubble?

You can find me underwater, but I won't be wet.

> perhaps an air bubble

You can find me in the air too, but I can't cross in between.

> Bubbles float in the air but don't last

In either case, I charge to my death, spilling my guts.

> pop!

If you touch me, I will die but if you carry me, you will die.

> I think this might be some sort of phrase not in my language.

If you guess the wrong thing, the OP will have to kill me.

> Well, if I'm wrong, at least one of the Powerpuff Girls is safe!

Comment: Right answer but Gordon K got the complete thing first. +1 for being the first to get the right object and for the powerpuff girls joke

Comment: Looks like the carrying a bubble is some sort of reference to heart failure or a stroke I guess.

Comment: @Kingrames No, bubbles in your blood will literally kill you.